# Absolutely identical pages behaving differently

Tags: php, paypal

I'm having problems getting a Paypal button to work on my site, and in order to test the issue thoroughly, I created a duplicate of a page with a button that works. When I say 'created a duplicate', I copy/pasted the entire code from one window of Notepad ++ to another. They should be identical. They are in the same folder of the website.

In the duplicate, the Paypal button, as well as the pound signs, don't work.

The original page, which works, is at http://www.sidekickbooks.com/laboratorio.php

The duplicate is at http://www.sidekickbooks.com/buttontest.php

I should say that when I click to 'view source' on the website, the pound signs have been replaced with `'+Â£'` (which is probably linked to the Paypal button not working). However, in the file I'm uploading, these are clean pound signs. I have no idea why, on this .php file and not the other, the substitution is being made.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like you have different encodings in your files.

Comment: try changing charset=iso-8859-1 / latin1 for utf-8

Comment: Hi - as it happens, I'd just got round to trying this myself before checking back here. Changing to utf-8 brings the pound signs back but the Paypal button still doesn't work in the duplicate.

And it still leaves me confused as to why the two identical pages should work differently. All I can think is that there's a conflict of some sort?

Comment: Here's a version with utf-8: http://www.sidekickbooks.com/buttontest2.php

Comment: Also, here's a completely clean html (not php) file with the Paypal button in it. Notepad++ has encoded it in UTF-8 and the META in the head sets it as UTF-8. And *still* the button doesn't work - the same button that works completely fine in the original file.

http://www.sidekickbooks.com/buttontest3.html

Comment: try <meta charset="UTF-8"> instead of content="text/html; charset=utf-8" at the top of the page. Encode your files in notepad ++ to UTF-8, and add header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); before any html tag

Answer (score 2):

Its a character encoding problem.

[article](https://webmonkeyuk.wordpress.com/2011/04/23/how-to-avoid-character-encoding-problems-in-php/)

Comment: Thanks very much for this. It's almost certainly the issue, but I'm having real trouble following it. For my test page, I'm using Notepad++ and have set it to encode in UTF-8. I've also made sure the META tag in the top specifies UTF-8. So far, the test page button still isn't working, so I'm struggling to work out where I would insert the "ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8')" to make sure the HTTP response headers line up all right.